# Showing cropped image in bokeh

Tags: javascript, python, user-interface, bokeh

I am showing a picture in a figure in bokeh and am using the `BoxSelectTool` in order to draw a rectangle.

```
box_select = BoxSelectTool(callback=callback)

p2 = figure(x_range=(0,700), y_range=(0,500),plot_width=1100,plot_height=1100,tools=[box_select])
p2.image_url( url='url',
         x=1, y=1, w=700, h=500, anchor="bottom_left",source=im_src)

rect_source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=[], y=[], width=[], height=[]))
callback = CustomJS(args=dict(rect_source=rect_source), code="""
    // get data source from Callback args
    var data = rect_source.data;

    /// get BoxSelectTool dimensions from cb_data parameter of Callback
    var geometry = cb_data['geometry'];

    /// calculate Rect attributes
    var width = geometry['x1'] - geometry['x0'];
    var height = geometry['y1'] - geometry['y0'];
    var x = geometry['x0'] + width/2;
    var y = geometry['y0'] + height/2;

    /// update data source with new Rect attributes
    data['x'].push(x);
    data['y'].push(y);
    data['width'].push(width);
    data['height'].push(height);

    rect_source.data = data;
    rect_source.change.emit();
'''
```

Now I want to show that image region as cropped in a different, smaller figure, after the rectangle is drawn, without clicking a button or anything:

```
d2 = figure(x_range=(0,200), y_range=(0,100),plot_width=200,plot_height=100)
d2.image( image='image',
         x=1, y=1, dw=100, dh=100, source=img)

img = ColumnDataSource( data=dict(image=[]))
```

So I need something like this in JS:

```
tmp_im = cv2.imread('static/' + str(im_nr) + '.jpg')
tmp_im = tmp_im[geometry['y0']:geometry['y1'],geometry['x0']:geometry['x1']]
tmp_im = cv2.cvtColor(tmp_im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img.data = dict(image=[tmp_im])
```

How can I do that in JS + bokeh?

Comment: "How can I do that in JS + bokeh?" should read "Python + bokeh", right?

Comment: I am currently using a CustomJS callback, so that is written in JS, but if there's a way to do it in Python, even better

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use the module `holoviews` (part of the pyviz ecosystem) for this task, which provides a high-level access to bokeh.

`Holoviews` provides so called `streams`, which can be used together with `DynamicMaps` to generate dynamic figures based on the (changing) values of the stream.

The module `panel` (also part of the pyviz ecosystem) can be used to define layouts for visualization.

```py
import numpy as np
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews import opts
from holoviews.streams import BoundsXY
import panel as pn

pn.extension() # loading the panel extension for use with notebook
opts.defaults(opts.Image(tools=['box_select'])) # making sure, that box_select is available

minval, maxval = 0, 200

# x-y data
ls = np.linspace(minval, 10, maxval)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(ls, ls)
# z-data, e.g. intensity
zz = xx*yy

# min and max, later used to recalibrate the colormapping
zzmin = zz.min()
zzmax = zz.max() 

bounds=(0,0, 1,1) # bounds used for the image
im = hv.Image(zz, bounds=bounds)

# stream, xy-data are provided by the box_select-tool
# As start values the same bounds as for the image are used.
box = BoundsXY(bounds=bounds) 

# The box-stream is used to draw a rectangle dynamically
# based on the current selection using the box_select-tool.
rect = hv.DynamicMap(
    lambda bounds: hv.Bounds(bounds),
    streams=[box])

# The box-stream is used to draw an image dynamically
# based on the current selection using the box_select-tool.
im_select = hv.DynamicMap(
    lambda bounds: im[bounds[0]:bounds[2],bounds[1]:bounds[3]],
    streams=[box])

# Arranging the layout.
# With redim.range we make sure the colormapping uses the original min- and max-values as in 'im',
# and not the min- and max-values from 'im_select'.
layout = pn.Row(im * rect \
                +\
                im_select.redim.range(z=(zzmin, zzmax))) 
layout.app()
```

[image]